# Unable to dispatch task for application, there are 1 tasks in progress

Tags: r, shiny

When attempting to deploy my Shiny application, I received the following error message:

```
Error: HTTP 409
POST https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/194614/deploy
Unable to dispatch task for application=194614, there are 1 tasks in progress
Execution halted
```

Why is this happening? Is there anything I can do to stop the tasks that are in progress?

Answer (score 1):

Delete "rsconnect" folder and restart the r session.
and repeat the deployment steps.